# Best way to call a method in a different view?

Tags: iphone, methods, sdk, controller, void

So I am going to get straight to the point. I need from one view controller (FolderViewController) to be able to call a -(void) on my other view controller (MainViewController). The method I want to call will refresh the servers based on which folder the user picked. How would I call the -(void) each time one of the folders is picked efficiently?

Here is my didselectPathAtIndexRow: on my FolderViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MainViewController *demoController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"server"] isEqualToString:@"imap.mail.me.com"]){
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"INBOX";
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Sent Messages";
        if (indexPath.row == 2)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Drafts";
        if (indexPath.row == 3)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Deleted Messages";
        if (indexPath.row == 4)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Archive";
        if (indexPath.row == 5)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Junk";
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"INBOX";
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/Starred";
        if (indexPath.row == 2)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
        if (indexPath.row == 3)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/Drafts";
        if (indexPath.row == 4)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/Trash";
        if (indexPath.row == 5)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/All Mail";
        if (indexPath.row == 6)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"[Gmail]/Spam";
    }
}
```

And here is the -(void) on my MainViewController:

```
- (void)refreshTheServers {

    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{}];

    KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeychainTest" accessGroup:nil];

    NSString *userForConnect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)]];
    NSString *passForConnect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]];



    CTCoreAccount *account = [[CTCoreAccount alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
        [account connectToServer:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                  stringForKey:@"server"]
                            port:993
                  connectionType:CTConnectionTypeTLS
                        authType:CTImapAuthTypePlain
                           login:userForConnect
                        password:passForConnect];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // ... the thread is over, do stuff on the main thread ...

            CTCoreFolder *inbox = [account folderWithPath:theAppDelegate.folder];

            NSArray *inboxMessages = [inbox messagesFromUID:1 to:0 withFetchAttributes:CTFetchAttrEnvelope];

            [[self allMessages] removeAllObjects];
            [[self allMessages] addObjectsFromArray:inboxMessages];

            [self.messagesTable reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: where did you add the instance from mainviewcontroller? witch navigation are you using?

Comment: It is in my MainViewController.m file.

Comment: yes but where did add the object reference? window, uinavigation tab bar , ...

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand. It is called each time I want to reload the UITableView because of switching folders, etc.

Comment: well if you have the reference just add the method in interface to be visible and call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A notification is a good way to signal between fairly unrelated classes like this. It gets the message through without creating a lot of dependencies between your classes. Your FolderViewController doesn't need full access to your MainViewController, so you don't really want to put a reference between them.

At the end of the method in FolderViewController, put this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangedFolder" object:nil];
```

Somewhere in the initialization of your MainViewController (`init` or `viewDidLoad`, e.g.), put this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshTheServers) name:@"ChangedFolder" object:nil];
```